# How do I verify my www domain after verifying the non-www domain in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console

I have setup a 301 redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://www.example.com` and I have already verified the non-www version.

- How do I verify the www version of my site?
- Can I use the same verification code and method?

Comment: Have you tried verifying this property and you got an error? What error did you get?

Comment: actually i have verified for non www when i trying to select www version as a preferred domain at that time got an error like please verify `http://.www.example.com` domain

Comment: So, verify the www version in the same way.

Comment: I also has the same query, Once I verify the other non www version, I will get code from Google. So do we need to have 2 verification code for one website? or do we need to delete old verification code.

Comment: @Tabassum you should notice that the google verify code is the same, because the code references your *ACCOUNT*. not your domain. It's quick and easy to verify multiple domains that feed back to the same server account

Answer (score 1):

Go in your Google Search Console (Webmaster Tools) dashboard and add your www domain (http://**www**.example.com) as a new domain. Then proceed with the owner verification just like you did with the non-www domain of yours.

If you have not changed your default settings for Virtual Hosts, the directory for both domains remains the same, so you upload the owner verification file at the same place as you did for your non-www domain owner verification.

After that, it is important to set your preferred domain after submitting your www and non-www domain so you have crawled and indexed only one domain by Google Search Engine.

From https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en

> ### Specify a preferred domain:
>
> **1.** On the Search Console Home page, click the site you want.
>
> **2.** Click the gear icon , and then click Site Settings.
>
> **3.** In the Preferred domain section, select the option you want.
>
> ....
>
> **Note:** Once you've set your preferred domain, you may want to use a 301 redirect to redirect traffic from your non-preferred domain, so
>   that other search engines and visitors know which version you prefer.

Comment: hi,is verification file same for both version or what? coz i have verified with the same verification code